# Can a battery powered circuit experience input voltage overshoot on turn-on?

Tags: switch-mode-power-supply

I'm trying to track down why my [SMPS stopped working](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/164674/troubleshooting-an-smps). One thing that caught my attention is this paragraph in the datasheet for the regulator:

[image]

I'm using a 2700mAh 3S LiPo (rated at 35C, 70C peak) connected through about 18" of speaker wire to the circuit, and turning it on/off with a SPST switch spliced into the V+ line.

I'll be the first to admit that I don't entirely understand the process described in this paragraph, but it does appear that I have the ingredients for what they describe, and don't have the tantalum cap across VIN.

So - can the fact that I'm using long-ish leads to a battery cause the ringing / overshoot described?

Circuit for reference:
[image]

SMPS for reference:
http://www.ti.com/lit/ds/symlink/tps62125.pdf

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, it's possible. The length of the leads is not so important as the area of the loop encircled by the leads. If they're a twisted pair it's a lot better than if you have two parallel wires, and much, much better than if one of the leads goes walkabout your chassis to a switch or something.

I suggest hanging a good old aluminum electrolytic across the input.. lots of capacitance and ESR to damp any ringing. Using tantalums 'bare' with a very low impedance battery source is asking for pyrotechnics of sorts, as any reputable maker should warn you. If it's a CR2032 etc. then, no problem.

Comment: Is there an optimal size for the cap, or just the biggest that I can stuff in?

Comment: .. and does adding the cap eliminate the need to manage the power cable routing?

Comment: Something like 100uF-470uF is probably a good match. Yes, you should not have to worry about power cable routing with a big input filter cap.